# Trying to speed up the startup launch in an Android app

Tags: android, firebase, performance, startup

in the process of improving my Android app startup launch time, I ended up with the concept of multidex and the fact that the number of components added in build.gradle slows down the launch time.

So how can I improve that, how can I lazy init some of the components that are not required at startup?
And using the lazy initialization, how can I identify the 3rd party components by class name. I understand that I could generate a maindexlist file, listing all the class names. But I'm not sure I know how to continue from that. Do I have to lazy init all the components one by one (I mean those unnecessary at startup)? Is this a good approach to speed my app launch time? Besides that, is the profiling in Android Studio shwoing also the startup initialization of those 3rd party components? If yes, how can I see them in the profile trace?

Perhaps I'm not being very clear. My app build.gradle file looks like this:

```
implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.1'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.0'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.1.0'
implementation "androidx.startup:startup-runtime:1.0.0"

//GOOGLE PLAY SERVICES
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:18.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.7.0'

// Google Sign In SDK (only required for Google Sign In)
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:19.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.6.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:17.5.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:17.0.0'

//places
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.1.0'


def multidex_version = "2.0.1"
implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:$multidex_version"

//maps
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0'

implementation project(path: ':app:libs:linkedin-sdk')
implementation project(path: ':app:libs:ntp:library')
implementation project(path: ':app:libs:ntp:library-extension-rx')
implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.2"


testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
implementation 'androidx.leanback:leanback-preference:1.0.0'

implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.0'
//implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.0.1'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.5.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:19.0.2'

// Facebook Android SDK (only required for Facebook Login)
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[5,6)'

//twitter
implementation 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:3.1.1'

implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'


//billing
implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:3.0.0'

//geo fire
implementation 'com.firebase:geofire-android:3.0.0'

//gson
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'


// Room Architecture Components.
implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1'
annotationProcessor 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1'

//biometrics
implementation 'androidx.biometric:biometric:1.0.1'

implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.10.1'
implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.10.1'
implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.10.1'

implementation 'org.whispersystems:signal-service-android:2.13.9'
```

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

These "components" are loaded at start because the OperationSystem cannot know when a component will be required, so...
If you know that (i.e.) Picasso is not loaded until "Page 9", then the only solution is to manually build a separated APK and MANUALLY load its class/dex file in runtime when needed. The procedure is not very easy and needs programming knownledge about Dex loading.